# Table that wouldn't appear in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a static tableview with three rows I am creating programatically.  I was creating it (incorrectly) in ViewDidAppear

```
   CGRect fr = CGRectMake(10, 100, 280, 150);
   SetUpTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:fr style:UITableViewStylePlain];
   SetUpTableView.autoresizingMask =    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
   SetUpTableView.delegate = self;
   SetUpTableView.dataSource = self;
   [self.view addSubview:SetUpTableView];
```

it was working fine.

I realized it was in the wrong location so i moved it to viewDidLoad

The table would NOT appear.

I commented out the auto resizing

```
   CGRect fr = CGRectMake(10, 100, 280, 150);
   SetUpTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:fr style:UITableViewStylePlain];
   // SetUpTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
   SetUpTableView.delegate = self;
   SetUpTableView.dataSource = self;
   [self.view addSubview:SetUpTableView];
```

and it now works fine in viewDidLoad.

I understand that I was in the wrong spot AND that this is a static table that doesn't need autoresizing but why would it work in viewDidAppear but not work in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Static tables (from what I know) can be created only using UITableViewController, you are creating a normal UITableView, you should post the code with data source and delegate methods. (Datasource methods are the most important for now). Also you can check if datasource methdos (`cellForRow`, `numberOfRows` etc) are called.

Comment: `SetUpTableView` should really be `setUpTableView` - it's traditional to use lowercase first letters for variables and uppercase for class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about timing.

> - `viewWillAppear` is called after the view hierarchy has finished being laid out. This means that whatever voodoo the auto resizing caused will be overridden by layout-related operations performed here.
> - `viewDidLoad` is called before the view has finished being laid out - this means that auto-resizing will occur **after** the code in `viewDidLoad` is executed.

Hope this clarifies things

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad`, how big is your `view`?

You have got magic numbers in your code - `CGRectMake(10, 100, 280, 150);`. If you want the tableview to be a fixed size from the left top right and bottom of your view, work it out, don't assume that you know the size of the view already!

Something like :

```
CGSize container = self.view.frame.size;
CGRect fr = CGRectMake(10, 100, container.width-60, container.height-100);
```

Otherwise, you might place your tableview outside the view and the autoresizing mask is just confused!